# Url rewriting not working with wordpress unless using [R]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress installation on my website on the folder `blog-ita/`. Now, I'd like to add a rewrite rule to allow accessing it from `website-name/blog/`.

I used this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^website-name/blog/(.*)$ blog-ita/$1
```

Now, this works if I add the [R] tag, but otherwise I get the 404 not found page from wordpress instead of the page I wanted to see.

How can that be? How can I make this work without the `[R]` flag?

Comment: Following the steps in [this guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) might help you. I can't test if this works too if you want to use any other directory than root. Otherwise you have to proxy the request.

Comment: Yes it works with other directories too, thanks! You should post this as answer, as it is the answer.

Comment: I have written an answer for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [this guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) from Wordpress to get Wordpress to work in a different directory than wordpress is actually located.

You want to install wordpress in the `blog-ita` directory. You want the url to show `website-name/blog` instead. Follow the following steps:

1. Go to the "General" panel in your admin section and change/check the following boxes, then save the changes:

   - Site address (URL): Change this to `http://example.com/website-name/blog`
   - Make sure that WordPress address is correctly configured as `htttp://example.com/blog-ita`.
2. Copy the index.php and .htaccess files in `/blog-ita` and paste them in `/website-name/blog`. **You need to copy, not move.**
3. Open the index.php file in `/website-name/blog` in your favourite text editor and change the line that says `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );` to point at the same file in the directory where wordpress is installed. In this case it should be changed to `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '../blog-ita/wp-blog-header.php' );`. Save the changes.

From this point on, wordpress should be available at `http://example.com/website-name/blog/`. The admin section is only available at the actual installation directory (`/blog-ita/admin`).