# How can I do this redirect with .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using Wordpress. How can I do this redirect with .htaccess file?

e.g. from **domain.com/blog/hello-world/** to **domain.com/hello-world/**

Thanks.

Edit: hello-world is not a folder. It is a page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url rewriting not working with wordpress unless using \[R\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362629/url-rewriting-not-working-with-wordpress-unless-using-r)

Comment: No, my question is different. hello-world is not a folder. It is a page.

Comment: Your Wordpress blog was located under `/blog/` and now you want it to be located under `/`. Read my answer on that question and click the link to the Wordpress guide. It will tell you how to do that.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Thanks. http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use Redirect Directive

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /blog/hello_world/ /hello_world/
```

Comment: I tried it. Redirect 301 /blog/merhaba-dunya/ /merhaba-dunya/

Redirect is successful but blog page does not open.

http://laysos.com/blog/ click to "Merhaba dünya!" blog post. You can see.

Comment: Hi @Starkeen. But does not open blog post. You can try it. Enter this address ( http://laysos.com/blog/ ) and click the "Merhaba dünya!" post. "Merhaba dünya!" does not open.