# Remove Duplicate Identical Slugs in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently sitting with a blog url that looks like this:

```
www.thedomain.com/blog/blog/blog-post
```

sitting in the root folder (it is WordPress).

I want to be able to remove one blog in the URL. I tried adding this in my `.htaccess` file but I get an error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ http://www.thedomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if your real URL is blog/blog/blog-post then yes  redirecting to a non existent URL is not going to work. You can not redirect to itself when it already is not a real location.

Comment: Is this Wordpress? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362629/url-rewriting-not-working-with-wordpress-unless-using-r/25385434#25385434

Comment: Why can't you just move the site up a level instead of trying to manipulate the URL.

Comment: @PanamaJack  
I can't move the site up one level - it is already in the root folder. I just want a way to replace the one /blog/ or completely remove it. At the moment my site is going to a 404

Comment: @Archie22is - so you are saying that there is no folder called `blog`? How do you get `blog/blog` then? Please share your directory structure.