# How to redirect properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I´m trying to redirect with rewrite rules in Apache .htaccess.
I want to redirect 360invest.pl to 360investment.pl.

But I want one more address on the server which I do NOT want to be redirected. If somebody tries **360invest.pl/bezrzecze** it should *not* redirect to 360investment.pl.

I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^360invest.pl/bezrzecze$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^360invest.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.360investment.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works only if you try www.360invest.pl/bezrzecze. It doesn't work if you try http://360invest.pl/bezrzecze.

In addition if you click any link on the website (www.360invest.pl/bezrzecze) it will redirect you to www.360investment.pl - it should not.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is really messy. The first condition does not make sense, because "360invest.pl/bezrzecze" is not a domain name. It is a domain name and a path. The following conditions with `[OR]` flags make no sense to me.

Think about what you want to accomplish. Start with the general case, then list your exceptions:

- If someone goes to `360invest.pl` you want to redirect all urls to `360investment.pl`
- **unless** someone goes to the path `bezrzecze`

The first part is the rule. The second part is a condition that has to be met

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bezrzecze
RewriteRule ^ http://www.360investment.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Please give me the whole code.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". This is all you need except for the `RewriteEngine on` directive.

Comment: If you click something on the website an error occurs.

Comment: Are both sites run on the same server from the same directory? What kind of error do you get? Do you get an internal server error, or does it complain about infinite redirects?

Comment: That websites are in different directories but on the same server. It complain about infinite redirects.

Comment: Please press F12 in your browser, go to the network tab, preserve the log and go to `http://360invest.pl/url-you-have-not-tested-with-before`. Please inspect the urls the browser redirects too. Please verify that you only see 302 redirects. Please make sure that the .htaccess file you are using is in the Document root of 360invest.pl and that the document root of 360investment.pl is not a subdirectory of the document root of 360invest.pl.

Comment: I see only 302 redirects but I've noticed there are one more htacces in path bezrzecze `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: Ah, good old Wordpress. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362629/url-rewriting-not-working-with-wordpress-unless-using-r/25385434#25385434) for more information.

Comment: Okay I have read that post and I made changes but something is missing. If you click on some links it still redirects to 360investment.pl It's crazy.